# newline at end of newcommand

Tags: spacing, macros

I have a newcommand defining a special paragraph (it's for a cheatsheet document):

```
\newcommand{\command}[2]{#1~\dotfill{}~#2\\}
```

I'm using it in the document in the following way:

```
\command{A}{Desc A}
\command{B}{Desc B}
\command{C}{Desc C}

Other section of my doc.
```

This code generates me a warning on line with `\command{C}`:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines <n>--<m>
```

I understand it's because this line is followed by a blank line.

So one solution I found to avoid this warning is to change my definition to:

```
\newcommand{\command}[2]{#1~\dotfill{}~#2}
```

(without the new line). And use it the following way:

```
\command{A}{Desc A}\\
\command{B}{Desc B}\\
\command{C}{Desc C}

Other section of my doc.
```

But I find it's not super clean, is it a way to do it automatically?

In fact, I want `\command` to act like a paragraph.

Comment: If you want it to act like a paragraph, finish the definition of `\command` with `\par` instead of \\.  That is a better way for many reasons, one of which is the behavior you cite.

Comment: A common mistake for new users is to micromanage LaTeX with the wanton use of \\.  Outside of `tabular` and aligning applications, \\ should be used sparingly if at all.  Generally, there is a proper LaTeX way to do what one is trying to otherwise accomplish with a \\.  So, anytime you get the urge to insert a \\, ask yourself, what am I *really* trying to accomplish at this location in the document?  And look for a better way.